# SQL alter statement and foreign/primary keys

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm in need of help in adding a primary and foreign key referencing from the staffs table onto staffposition table, branchno from table branch and main primary key as date started. StaffsNo being both PK and FK. It's really bugging me.. I get the error "ORA-01735: invalid ALTER TABLE option"... Can anybody provide input? Cheers in advance!

```
ALTER TABLE StaffPosition
add CONSTRAINT StaffPosition_pk PRIMARY KEY (DateStarted, StaffsNo),
add FOREIGN KEY (StaffsNo) REFERENCES Staffs(StaffsNo),
add FOREIGN KEY (BranchNo) REFERENCES Branch(BranchNo);
```

Comment: Good luck with your project. And if you ever have a question about it, feel free to post it here!

Answer (score 1):

You need to separate these into distinct `alter table` statements; you can't issue one to add them all:

```
ALTER TABLE StaffPosition
add CONSTRAINT StaffPosition_pk PRIMARY KEY (DateStarted, StaffsNo);
ALTER TABLE StaffPosition
add CONSTRAINT fk1 FOREIGN KEY (StaffsNo) REFERENCES Staffs(StaffsNo),
ALTER TABLE StaffPosition
add CONSTRAINT fk2 FOREIGN KEY (BranchNo) REFERENCES Branch(BranchNo);
```

Comment: Ah right, I see cheers! I've not used the alter statement as much because I just create the table and add the constraints below. But I forgot hence I'm using alter statements. But now I'm getting "ORA-00911: invalid character" lol.